# Change key array based other array

Tags: php

The first array has the same keys as those in the `sheet` key content in the second array.

I would need to edit the key element of the first array, with the contents that I have in the key `table` in the second array, according to the key`sheet`

I tried in countless ways but without success, here is an illustrative image

the first:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [CIDADES] => PONTA GROSSA
                [PERIODO] => 12:00 - 18:00
                [ID] => Z8932
                [END] => AV VSC DE MAUA,, ALT 
                [CONTRATO] => 7947488
                [AREA] => AR01
                [ASSINANTE] => DAVI
                [BAIRRO] => OFICINAS
                [OBS] => [Agendamento par]  
                [TEL RES] => 42410435
                [TEL COM] => 
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [CIDADES] => PONTA GROSSA
                [PERIODO] => 08:00 - 12:00
                [ID] => Z7526
                [END] => R P1000, FD 
                [CONTRATO] => 799644
                [AREA] => AR01
                [ASSINANTE] => BEATRIZ
                [BAIRRO] => NEVES
                [OBS] => [Agendamento]  
                [TEL RES] => 42988674761
                [TEL COM] => 
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [CIDADES] => PONTA GROSSA
                [PERIODO] => 08:00 - 12:00
                [ID] => Z0979
                [END] => R J93, FD 
                [CONTRATO] => 79490
                [AREA] => AR01
                [ASSINANTE] =>FERNANDES  REIS
                [BAIRRO] => UVARANAS
                [OBS] => [Agendamentoente] 
                [TEL RES] => 4289986
                [TEL COM] => 
            )
    )
```

And the second

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [table] => id_operacao
                [sheet] => CIDADES
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [table] => horario
                [sheet] => PERIODO
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 3
                [table] => tipo_wo
                [sheet] => TIPO DE SERVICO
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [id] => 4
                [table] => tecnico_id
                [sheet] => ID
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [id] => 5
                [table] => contrato
                [sheet] => CONTRATO
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [id] => 6
                [table] => roteamento
                [sheet] => AREA
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [id] => 7
                [table] => endereco
                [sheet] => END
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [id] => 8
                [table] => nome_cliente
                [sheet] => ASSINANTE
            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [id] => 9
                [table] => bairro
                [sheet] => BAIRRO
            )

        [9] => Array
            (
                [id] => 10
                [table] => obs1
                [sheet] => OBS
            )

        [10] => Array
            (
                [id] => 11
                [table] => telefone
                [sheet] => TEL RES
            )

        [11] => Array
            (
                [id] => 12
                [table] => celular
                [sheet] => TEL COM
            )
    )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey man I skipped a few items in the array but hopefully I got the structure right ;)

```
$firstArray = [
    [
        'CIDADES' => 'PONTA GROSSA',
        'PERIODO' => '12:00 - 18:00',
        'ID' => 'Z8932',
        'END' => 'AV VSC DE MAUA,, ALT',
        'CONTRATO' => '7947488',
        'AREA' => 'AR01',
        'ASSINANTE' => 'DAVI',
        'BAIRRO' => 'OFICINAS',
        'OBS' => ['Agendamento par'],
        'TEL RES' => '42410435',
    ],
    [
        'CIDADES' => 'PONTA GROSSA',
        'PERIODO' => '08:00 - 12:00',
        'ID' => 'Z7526',
        'END' => 'R P1000, FD',
        'CONTRATO' => '799644',
        'AREA' => 'AR01',
        'ASSINANTE' => 'DAVI',
        'BAIRRO' => 'BEATRIZ',
        'OBS' => ['Agendamento'],
        'TEL RES' => '42988674761',
    ],
    [
        'CIDADES' => 'PONTA GROSSA',
        'PERIODO' => '08:00 - 12:00',
        'ID' => 'Z0979',
        'END' => 'R J93, FD',
        'CONTRATO' => '79490',
        'AREA' => 'AR01',
        'ASSINANTE' => 'FERNANDES  REIS',
        'BAIRRO' => 'UVARANAS',
        'OBS' => ['Agendamentoente'],
        'TEL RES' => '4289986',
    ],
];

$secondArray = [
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'table' => 'id_operacao',
        'sheet' => 'CIDADES',
    ],
    [
        'id' => 2,
        'table' => 'horario',
        'sheet' => 'PERIODO',
    ],
    [
        'id' => 3,
        'table' => 'tipo_wo',
        'sheet' => 'TIPO DE SERVICO',
    ],
    [
        'id' => 4,
        'table' => 'tecnico_id',
        'sheet' => 'ID',
    ],
    [
        'id' => 5,
        'table' => 'contrato',
        'sheet' => 'CONTRATO',
    ],
    [
        'id' => 6,
        'table' => 'roteamento',
        'sheet' => 'AREA',
    ],
    [
        'id' => 7,
        'table' => 'endereco',
        'sheet' => 'END',
    ],
    [
        'id' => 8,
        'table' => 'nome_cliente',
        'sheet' => 'ASSINANTE',
    ],
];

//I guess this is what you were missing most
$oldKeysToNewKeys = array_combine(
    array_column($secondArray, 'sheet'),
    array_column($secondArray, 'table')
);

foreach ($firstArray as $key => $firstArrayElements) {
    $newFirstArrayElement = [];
    foreach ($firstArrayElements as $oldKey => $value) {
        //You could add checks to avoid errors when keys are not set etc..
        $newKey = $oldKeysToNewKeys[$oldKey];
        $newFirstArrayElement[$newKey] = $value;
    }
    $firstArray[$key] = $newFirstArrayElement;
}

//There you go!
var_dump($firstArray);
```